# Decomposability of positive maps

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

By results of Størmer and Woronowicz, every positive map $\Phi \colon \mathcal{M}_{d \times d} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{d' \times d'}$ for $dd' \leq 6$  can be decomposed as a convex combination

$$\Phi = p \phi + (1-p) ~ T \circ \psi$$

where $\phi$, $\psi$ are *completely* positive maps and $T$ is the transposition map.

For higher dimensions, this is in general false.
Does there however (for fixed $d$, $d'$) exist a *finite set* of positive maps $(P_i)$ such that every general positive map $\Phi$ is a convex combination

$$\Phi = \sum p_i P_i \circ \phi_i$$

where the $\phi_i$ are suitably chosen completely positive maps?

Comment: Perhaps you should give the definition of *positive map*, as well as of *completely positive map*.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. A linear map $\Phi$ of $C^*$-algebras is _positive_ if sends the positive cone to the positive cone.
It is _$k$-positive_ if $\Phi$ tensored with the identity map on $k \times k$-matrices is positive.
It is _completely positive_ if is $k$-positive for all $k > 0$.

Comment: Maybe I'm worng, but I thought that is an open problem at the heart of quantum information theory (?)

Comment: Michael, would you please include a reference for the first decomposition you mention, or at least to the specific results of Stormer and Woronowicz that lead to it?

Comment: Jon, the results can be found in the articles "Positive maps of low dimensional matrix algebras" (Woronowicz) and "Positive linear maps of operator algebras" (Størmer).

Comment: Stefan, I have seen it described as an open problem in the book "Geometry of Quantum States" (and should have mentioned that in my question), but was wondering whether there were any more recent (partial) results (e.g. for the already interesting case $d = d' = 3$).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm quite late answering this question, but I figured it still deserves an answer. The answer to your question is "no": when $d,d^\prime \geq 3$ there does not exist such a finite (or even countable) set of positive maps.

In [arXiv:1209.0437](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0437), we considered the following problem: given a set of positive maps $\mathcal{Q}$ from $\mathcal{M}_d$ to $\mathcal{M}_{d^\prime}$, what is the set

$$\mathcal{C}_\mathcal{Q} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{\sum_i \psi_i \circ P_i \circ \phi_i : P_i \in \mathcal{Q}, \psi_i \text{ and } \phi_i \text{ are completely positive for all $i$}\}?$$

As you noted, Størmer and Woronowicz showed that if $\mathcal{Q} = \{T\}$ (where $T$ is the transpose map) and $dd^\prime \leq 6$, then $\mathcal{C}_\mathcal{Q}$ is the set of all positive maps.

We didn't prove it in the paper, but as an offshoot Łukasz Skowronek proved in the $d,d^\prime\geq 3$ case that if $\mathcal{C}_\mathcal{Q}$ is the set of all positive maps then $\mathcal{Q}$ must be uncountable. I don't believe he ever did end up formally writing up the result, but he at least gave a talk about it (slides available [here](http://www.fizyka.umk.pl/zfmis/smp44/LNotes/Conference_talks/June_22/skowronek.pdf)).

The slides go through the proof in pretty good detail: the rough idea is that there is a known uncountably infinite set of positive maps on $\mathcal{M}_3$ that are each exposed in the set of positive maps and are all indecomposable (i.e., can not be written in the form $\phi_1 + T \circ \phi_2$ for some completely positive $\phi_1,\phi_2$) due to Ha and Kye (see [arXiv:1108.0130](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0130)). Łukasz showed that there is no countable set $\mathcal{Q}$ such that $\mathcal{C}_\mathcal{Q}$ contains even just this particular (relatively small) set of positive maps.

**Update [May 23, 2016]:** It seems that Łukasz finally got around to formally writing up this result, and it is now proved explicitly in [this new paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.05254)).